# PHP - If within an if

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to run some PHP code if the URL exactly matches whatever I specify...if the url doesn't match this it should do nothing. However if it does match the url, I want to run another statement to check if the user is logged in...if they are it should do nothing. If they are not it should redirect them. I have written some code for this but it doesn't seem to be working...any ideas?

Code is here:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'example.com') 
{
    //User is on main page
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       //Do nothing
        } else {
       header("Location: https://example.com/welcome");
        }
} else {/*do nothing*/}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to be working" - which part exactly in what way?

Comment: Define "not working".  What indication do you have that there's an error?

Comment: @VolkerK I have just updated post...put the if statement in the wrong area. Basically it doesn't redirect the user anywhere when they are on example domain.com even if they aren't logged in

Comment: Put in some basic debugging `echo`s to see which path is being taken.  Dump the result of `is_user_logged_in()` if that's being called.

Comment: why don't you use an `&&`? edit: ah, an answer was edited to that effect.

Comment: You may want `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` that will only work if you are asking for the server/file and not just server which is what you're looking to do here, least that's what I think. Plus, you may need to check against possible "www" also.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yep, that'll work also. Hard to say really what the OP wants to check against. Server and file? or just the server. No idea.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I literally want to check if the current page url is xxx. If it is, run the following function. It is so that I run this function on one page only

Comment: server and page are two different animals here. so `if($host == 'example.com')` will fail in using your current method and the answer given below.

Comment: if your web address is `www.example.com` then that too is failing you using `if($host == 'example.com')`. You need to check for multiple instances of `example.com/page.xxx` and `www.example.com/page.xxx`.

Comment: I just want to get the current page's url. I am trying this as it is on wordpress: `$url = home_url();
echo $url;` but still no luck

Comment: [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if($host == 'example.com' && !is_user_logged_in()) 
{
   header("Location: https://example.com/welcome");

} else {/*do nothing*/}
```

Comment: please see updated question...put the code in the wrong place - doh

Comment: best to use an `exit;` after header.

Comment: that looks like it should work to me but it doesn't....am I using the $host right? I want to check that my url - https://example.com - is as specified in the code.

Comment: how do I check that @Hareesh

Comment: `echo $host;` after `$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: It doesn't appear to echo anything.

Comment: Really? Try to simple put `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` before anything else in your code. At the very least it should give you localhost.

Comment: Also - just thought of this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698660/cron-script-doesnt-work-in-server-side/23698926#23698926 You are not running the scrips from a command line environment are you? I'd be weird to do `header("Location...` if you are - but it would explain why the _SERVER-array is empty.